# Can we get user name and email and\or any other user defining data from users openID via pure JS calls? (no server side at all)

Tags: javascript, openid, client-side

Is it possible to obtain data from user open id (for example such google one `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`) via pure JS calls (not using server side at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd be able to send XHR requests to other domains, it would be theoretically possible.
However, since browsers generally enforce same-origin policy, it's not. Also, if you do manage to send a request to another domain, you'd need to be able to parse both the returned content, and response headers (especially the Location and X-XRDS-Location).

However, it's pretty much pointless to try to implement OpenID in javascript, unless you are sure that your users don't have access to a debugger. If they do, they can modify the value of any variable, including the one where you store the user's identity, effectively making the system insecure.